# Can not write text to a file

Tags: c#, console-application

So, basically, I am trying to make a save point in my text rpg. I wanted to do it by using a .txt file and jumping to each method that way. However, when I try and put in the path of the file and the string contents, it returns a CS0029 error and states that it can not convert a void to a string.

```
public void PickingUpScroll()
    {

        savePoint = "PickingUpScroll";
        saveData = File.WriteAllText(savePath, savePoint);
         
        hasFireMagic = true;

        Console.WriteLine("You approach the strange scroll in your room and pick it up. A strange light eminates from the foreign symbols on the paper. You feel a warmth in your hands.\nLooking down, you notice they are glowing with a strange light, almost like fire.");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine("You have accquired 'Fire Magic'");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;


        if (hasWeapons == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you approach the weapons?\n[1] Yes [2] No");
            int scrollToSwordCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (scrollToSwordCheck == 1)
            {

                PickingUpSword();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            LeavingRoom();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could have made it much easier by telling us on which line the _compilation_ error occurred . Take a look at the docs for `WriteAllText` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_ ). It's declared as a `void` function, meaning it returns nothing. You can't assign the results of a void to anything

Comment: So.. why *did* you put `saveData = File.WriteAllText` ? What were you hoping saveData would end up containing? What would you later do with `saveData`? (What functionality are you hoping to implement?)

Comment: Come on guys (not you Flydog57) ...what part of _New contributor_ did you miss?

Comment: Can you add a comment above the line causing the error, please? What is the type of savePoint? String? What are the type and content of savePath? String? Not null? Also [WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext) returns nothing... here it is the problem as exposed by others: you can't assign the result of a procedure that is not a function because there is no result (void).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Considering that this is the first question you have posted here, it has all the information to be solved within seconds. Have an upvote for this. Please don't get discouraged in the beginning. I am sure you will improve with each question that you ask here. Have fun and happy coding. Please mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted.

Comment: Unrelated: _"int scrollToSwordCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());"_ - to save you headaches: _Do not trust user input_. Create a reusable function to retrieve input and validate it thoroughly. Users do and will enter stuff you don't expect them to.

Answer (score 7):

The File.WriteAllText method is a void (it doesn't return any value)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0

You can get rid of the variable saveData in the line:

```
saveData = File.WriteAllText(savePath, savePoint);
```

and just use the method:

```
File.WriteAllText(savePath, savePoint);
```

(and keep in mind that you will need to instantiate and assign the variable savePath somewhere prior its usage)